# tikzpicture ends up way outside the limits of the page

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, anchor

In my document which is defined as A4, I want to place our logo in the upper left corner of the first page. The code I'm using for this is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=1cm] at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I compile my document with `xelatex document.tex` no logo can be seen. When opening the PDF file in a graphic program, I find out that the logo has been included in the file, but positioned outside of the visible area of the page (way above the page and on the right side).

However if I compile my document with `latexmk -xelatex document.tex`, the logo appears exactly where I expect it to be. Just this method gives me the following warning:
*The following rules & subrules became out-of-date: 'xelatex'*.

For now this compilation method still works, but I would assume that the rule will stop working sometime in the future, so I'd like to find out why the other way of compiling breaks my document.

I'd be glad for any explanation, idea or tip on how to fix this.

Here a complete example document which demonstrates the same behaviour:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=1cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,nohead]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=1cm] at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{UniLogo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\center
\vspace{2cm}
\large Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\pagebreak[4]
\end{document}
```

P.S.: Just to be clear, the logo file does exist in the indicated path, and it is also correctly read and included, just the position is off.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a full example to my post.

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour/problem when replacing "UniLogo" with "example-image-a" ? If you do that, then others will be able to compile your code directly. In TexShop, I get the correct placement of the logo both with `LaTeX` and `XeLaTeX`. I also tried zsh compile with `xelatex` - ( `This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994` )without any problem. Is you system up to date?

Comment: It work fine, however for final result you need due to used `remember picture, overlay` compile at least twice.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, I get the same result with "example-image-a" and the same happens when using TexShop with both LaTeX and XeLaTeX. However the comment by Zarko seems to hit the nail on the head: when typesetting twice in a row, the logo appears.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks a lot for pointing this out. Indeed it works when I typeset twice. That's my reward for copying LaTeX snippets from the internet without understanding what they do … I'll look into the "remember picture, overlay" thing right away …